# Unable to post file to server using superagent

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, superagent

I have a react application (using webpack and running on localhost) and I am trying to send a text file to a server that I created separately, still locally
using Node.js (also on localhost but different port). For file upload, I use a library called [Dropzone](https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone). To send the file over, I am using a library called [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent).

The problem here is that when I send over a file, the server receives the request but not the file. Right before I send the file, I console logged the file to make sure that the object is available:

[image]

I've been trying the solutions that I found online but to no avail. I even console logged the request on the server side but found no req.body/req.files. I figured that I am doing something wrong with the superagent library. Below are the codes that I've tried. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**SERVER SIDE CODES**

***app.js(1st test)***

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Metadata = require('./Metadata.model');
var cors = require('cors');
const fs = require('fs');
var port = 3000;

var myDir = ('./tmp');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:8080'}));

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  try {
    fs.accessSync(myDir);
  } catch (e) {
    fs.mkdirSync(myDir);
  };
  console.log(req);
});
```

***app.js(2nd test)***

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Metadata = require('./Metadata.model');
var cors = require('cors');
const fs = require('fs');
var fileupload = require('fileupload').createFileUpload('/tmp').middleware;
var port = 3000;

var myDir = ('./tmp');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:8080'}));

app.post('/upload', fileupload, function(req, res) {
  console.log(req);
});
```

**CLIENT SIDE CODES**

***test_page.js(1st test)(full code)***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';
var request = require('superagent');

const ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';

class TestPage extends Component {

  onDrop(files){
    files.forEach((file) => {
      console.log(file);
      request.post(`${ROOT_URL}/upload`)
      .attach(file.name, file)
      .end((err, res) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(res);
      })
    });
  };

  onOpenClick(){
    this.refs.dropzone.open();
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Dropzone ref="dropzone" onDrop={this.onDrop}>
          <div>Drop files here</div>
        </Dropzone>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.onOpenClick.bind(this)}>
          Open Dropzone
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TestPage;
```

***test_page.js(1st test)(changed code)***

```
onDrop(files){
    files.forEach((file) => {
      console.log(file);
      request.post(`${ROOT_URL}/upload`)
      .set("Content-Type", "text/plain")//also tried ("Accept", "text/plain")
      .send(file)
      .end((err, res) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(res);
      })
    });
  };
```

Comment: Bodyparser does not support file uploads, use multer instead

Comment: @Ananth That was a big clue. Had to research a lil bit but got it working in the end. Thank you!